# Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined

Tags: node.js, promise

I am trying to use Argon2 encryption in Node, but when I try to encrypt a string, I get this error:

`Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined`

I have tried handling the errors from the promise returned by the `argon2.hash` function, but it still does not work.

This is my code so far:

```js
argon2.hash('password', {type: argon2.argon2id})
    .then(hash => {
        // do something with the hash
    }).catch(err => {
        // Handle the error
    });
```

Could anyone please help me with fixing this error?

Comment: What node version are you running?

Comment: Node version is: v10.15.3

Comment: Run the following code. What does it print? `console.log(argon2.hash('password', {type: argon2.argon2id}));` It should print `Promise`. But if it doesn't then, that's interesting.

Comment: It does print `Promise`

Answer (score 3):

In my case I got that error message because I

a) spied on some async method

```
spyOn(sut,'myAsyncMethod')
```

b) later appended .catch() to the original method call and forgot to extend the    spy to return a value/promise.

Returning a promise from the spy solved my issue:

```
spyOn(sut,'myAsyncMethod').and.returnValue(new Promise(resolve=>resolve()));
```

Answer (score 1):

It throws an exception, it does not return a promise. As such, there is no promise object on which the then(…).catch(…) methods could be invoked.

To catch it, you would need an actual try/catch block

from [argon2 github page](https://github.com/ranisalt/node-argon2), you should do this:

```
const argon2 = require('argon2');

try {
  const hash = await argon2.hash("password");
} catch (err) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: Your answer might be correct, but for the wrong reason. `argon2.hash` is an `async` function. Async functions always return a promise. So, the code above _should_ work. It may be that the OP is using an older version of node.

Comment: I have tried your code inside an `async` function and I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead:

```
argon2.hash('password', {type: argon2.argon2id})
  .then(hash => {
    // do something with the hash
}, err => {
    // Handle the error
});
```

The second parameter to a `then` clause is the onError handler.

Comment: I feel like there's something else going on. Can you create a plunkr or a code snippet for this so we can look at the running code?

Comment: I think I've sorted it. It was an error in my error-handling middleware that was being called after this function.